# Android: making a service non stoppable

Tags: android, android-service

I wonder if there is a way in Android to prevent a service from being stopped from the "running services" screen.

I've developed a service that is started from my app and I basically want to stop it only from my app; currently I can stop it by selecting my service and clicking stop on Applications->running services screen

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a security violation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent the system from closing your application/service. This can happen by killing the process as you described or when the system runs low on resources. In the last case it can be restarted if you returned START_STICKY from onStartCommand method.

Answer (score 1):

Nop, there's no way to avoid this. One can always kill a service from *Running Services* option